# Why does the execution of a program result in these context switches?

Tags: linux, unix, fork, perf, context-switch

Here is the source code of my program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    printf("Hello world (pid:%d)!\n", (int)getpid());
    int pipefd[2];
    int pipe_ret = pipe(pipefd);
    if (pipe_ret == -1) {
        printf("%s\n", strerror_l(errno, uselocale((locale_t)0)));
        exit(1);
    }

    int rc1 = fork();
    if (rc1 < 0) {  // fork failed; exit
        fprintf(stderr, "fork failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (rc1 == 0) {  // child (new process)
        printf("Hello, I am child (pid:%d)!\n", (int)getpid());
        dup2(pipefd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(pipefd[1]);
        int j = 0;
        while (j < 1) {
            scanf("%d", &j);
            printf("I am child %d and I have just read %d from the other child.\n",(int)getpid(), j);
        }
    }
    else {  // parent goes down this path (main)
        printf("Hello, I am parent of %d (pid:%d).\n", rc1, (int)getpid());
        int rc2 = fork();
        if (rc2 < 0) {  // fork failed; exit
            fprintf(stderr, "fork failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        else if (rc2 == 0) {  // child (new process)
            printf("Hello, I am child (pid:%d)!\n", (int)getpid());
            dup2(pipefd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
            close(pipefd[0]);
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                printf("%d\n", i);
                sleep(1);
            }
        }
        else {
            printf("Hello, I am parent of %d (pid:%d).\n", rc2, (int)getpid());
            wait(NULL); // Wait for any child process to finish
            wait(NULL); // Wait for the other child process to finish
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want to trace in which order the parent and child processes switch. Yet I want to do that from the outside of the program. For this purpose, I first use this command.

```
 perf record -e cs ./5_8
```

I have the following output.

```
Hello world (pid:9460)!
Hello, I am parent of 9462 (pid:9460).
Hello, I am parent of 9463 (pid:9460).
Hello, I am child (pid:9463)!
Hello, I am child (pid:9462)!
I am child 9462 and I have just read 0 from the other child.
I am child 9462 and I have just read 1 from the other child.
[ perf record: Woken up 1 times to write data ]
[ perf record: Captured and wrote 0.002 MB perf.data (13 samples) ]
```

It makes me think there are 13 context switches in total. Then to see the order, I use this command.

```
perf script -F comm,pid,event,time -f
```

I have this output.

```
5_8  9460  3151.197904: cs:
5_8  9460  3151.198436: cs:
5_8  9460  3151.198811: cs:
5_8  9460  3151.199271: cs:
5_8  9460  3151.199720: cs:
5_8  9460  3151.200381: cs:
5_8  9460  3151.201129: cs:
5_8  9463  3151.201185: cs:
5_8  9462  3151.201219: cs:
5_8  9463  3152.201512: cs:
5_8  9460  3152.201765: cs:
5_8  9460  3153.202438: cs:
5_8  9460  3153.203312: cs:
```

So the first question is why there are subsequent context switches between the process with PID 9460 (the parent) and itself. And why are there so many of them? How would one interpret them based on the source code?

The second question is whether the following interpretation is correct:

1. The first context switch of 9463 (the child who writes in the pipe) is after it popped in the first number (0) and invoked sleep().
2. The first context switch of the process with PID 9462 (the child that reads from the pipe) occurs after it has read the first number (0) and started waiting for the following number.
3. The second context switch of 9463 (the child who writes in the pipe) is after it popped in the second number (1) and invoked sleep().
4. There is no need for the second context switch for the process with PID 9462 (the child that reads from the pipe) since it terminates having read the second number.

Comment: According to `perf stat ./a.out` on my system (8 logical cores, Linux kernel 6.4.2 x86-64 Arch Linux), there were 6 context switches in each of two runs.  But `perf record -e cs` also reports recording only 6 samples (and perf script only has 6 lines), so it seems on your machine it actually did context-switch 13 times.  Do you maybe have a single-core VM or something, so a core has to context-switch to a terminal emulator when your code writes to the console?  Or to SSH if you're logged in remotely?  Does `perf stat ./a.out > /dev/null` change anything?

Comment: @Peter Cordes, I run the program using WSL on Windows. Can it be the cause? 'perf stat' logs 13 context switches.

Comment: That's possible.  I haven't used WSL.  Version 1 and 2 are very different, with WSL2 running an actual Linux kernel in a VM, vs. a system-call emulation layer.

Comment: @Peter Cordes, I use version 2 with Ubuntu if that clarifies anything. Thank you for the explanation. I'm going to move on and stop overthinking it. I think it's not vital.

Comment: I just tested on my system with `taskset -c 1  perf stat ./a.out`, to see if pinning it to a single core (#1) would make it context-switch more.  Turns out actually less: only 5 CSes.  So whatever WLS2 is doing, it's not an effect of running Linux on a single core (which I didn't think it would be doing anyway, but was worth trying to see what would happen.)  Hrm, actually with SSH or a terminal emulator all having to share a single core, that *could* lead to extra context switches; I was only pinning `a.out` and its children, not my `konsole` and X server.

Comment: @Peter Cordes, I have just tried `taskset -c 1  perf stat`, and it logged 0 context switches. I'm confused :)

Comment: On a multi-core machine, no context switches are *necessary*.  (I'm surprised we see zero CSes with `taskset -c 1`, though, I'd expect that to require some because different tasks need to take turns for this execution.)  If each child starts on a different core from the one where its parent executed `fork`, the `current` task on each of those cores can stay the same, just waking up when `sleep` times expire or when another core `write`s to a pipe buffer it was blocked on `read`ing from.  The terminal emulator controlling the pty it's running on (for printf output) could also be on another core

Comment: @Peter Cordes, precisely. If we force the program to run on a single CPU, we expect to see at least several context switches since there are forks. I have just noticed another bizarre thing. Many context switches occur only in the root mode, the same number regardless of whether there is `taskset -c 1` or not. When non-root, it logs 0 of them for both cases. So `taskset -c 1` doesn't change anything, yet the current mode being root, or non-root, is somehow a cornerstone.

Comment: Perhaps you have `/proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid` set in a way that stops the CS event from being counted?  It's a software event so I'd have thought it would be countable with any permission setting, but that's the major difference between `perf` as root or not, acting like paranoid = `-1`.  On my system I have it set to `0`.

Comment: @Peter Cordes, you're right. `/proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid` was 2. I changed it to -1. Now there are context switches registered when non-root. Thank you.